# Using coverlet with. Net Framework generates an error: The expression "[System.Version]::Parse('')" canot be evaluated

Tags: c#, .net-4.8, coverlet

I wrote a very simple C# .Net Framework application and added some unit tests. Now, trying to check the coverage using coverlet. Getting error MSB4184.

> The expression "[System.Version]::Parse('')" canot be evaluated. Version string portion was too short or too long. (parameter 'input' ).

Does anyone encounter such an error?

Comment: `[typename]::StaticMethod()` <-- is [tag:powershell] syntax, not C# - perhaps from your build script?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that's also Msbuild syntax (hence the MSB error) , so it's the Msbuild script

Comment: It looks like you are passing an empty string in, so "Version string portion was too short" is completely accurate.

Answer (score 7):

One way I got around this issue was by renaming (or deleting) the `coverlet.collector` directory in your `$HOME\.nuget\packages` directory. Close Visual Studio completely, then re-open your solution or project.

[image: File Explorer with renamed coverlet.collector directory]

Answer (score 2):

Coverlet has some limitations. It only supports SDK-style projects and in some cases only .NET Core test projects. This is not an issue if you start a new test project in a solution because you can mix up project types.

But migration of an existing old test project to an SDK style .NET Core project could be necessary.

https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet#Quick-Start has more information about the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using .Net6 for my test project rather than .Net 4.x .
the .Net6 library was still able to execute my functions in my .net4.x library and coverlet restored without any issues